# How do I specify non-scalar parameters in a Slim table?

Tags: vector, matrix, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I want to test functions that have non-scalar parameters and return types, *e.g.*, "given a matrix *M*, check that *M* times its inverse is the appropriate identity" or "given a row vector *V*, check that `transpose(V)` is the correct column vector.

Do I need a clever use of [`TableTable`](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.TableTable)?